# Modbus TCP with C#

Tags: modbus

I am trying to write io status to console from a device using modbus tcp protokol. I did it but I am closing and running the program again and again to see the changes of io status. I want to display the changes of io status real time. 
How can I display it in real time ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need just loop without condition? Like:
`While(!Console.ReadKey())
{
    showStatus();
}`
Please share more details about problem for correct answer.